# Signal value won't be initialized during simulation

Tags: vhdl, simulation

We've a project for college where we have to simulate a MAC unit for DSP.
For the simulation, I'm using Aldec Riviera Pro 2014.06 through EDA playground.
The problem is that even though I initialized a 32-bit signed signal named add_res, at the simulation its value will be shown as XXXX_XXXX the whole time.

[Here's the simulation's result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2lyY.png)

Here's the code of the design.vhd

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;
-----------------------------
ENTITY mac IS
      PORT (B, C : IN SIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0);
          clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
          A : OUT SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0));
END mac;
-----------------------------
ARCHITECTURE mac_rtl OF mac IS
      SIGNAL mul_res: SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0);
      SIGNAL add_res: SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
BEGIN

      mul_res <= B * C;

      PROCESS (clk)
      BEGIN
          A <= mul_res + add_res;
          add_res <= A;
      END PROCESS;

END mac_rtl;
```

And here's the code of the testbench.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity testbench is
end entity testbench;

architecture BENCH of testbench is
component mac is
port (B, C : in  SIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0);
      clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
      A : out SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0));
end component;

  signal StopClock : BOOLEAN;
  signal clk : STD_LOGIC;
  signal B, C : SIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0);
  signal A : SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0);

begin

  ClockGenerator: process
  begin
  clk <= '0';
  wait for 2 ns;
    while not StopClock loop
      clk <= '0';
      wait for 1 ns;
      clk <= '1';
      wait for 1 ns;
    end loop;
  wait;
  end process ClockGenerator;

  Stimulus: process 
  begin

  B <= "0000000000000010";
  C <= "0000000000001000";
  wait;

  end process Stimulus;

  DUT : entity work.mac
    port map (B, C, clk, A);

end architecture BENCH;
```

I've searched here and in Google in general for others having the same problem, but the solutions given didn't help.

I've tried and with a *Reset* variable from testbench, but nothing. It's like it won't be initialized at all, while everything else work normally.

Comment: You are trying to assign a port of mode `out` (`A`) to a signal (`add_res`), which is not possible

Comment: That's because I'm trying there to implement a feedback as it's shown here: [link](http://turbo-cf.narod.ru/docs/MCF5307/MCF5307BUM-MAC.pdf) page 2.

Comment: Reading a port of mode out is explicitly allowed in IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.2 Interface object declarations, para 13 "**out**. The value of the interface object is allowed to be updated and, provided it is not a signal parameter, read."  A signal parameter means a class signal interface object for a subprogram, see 6.5.2 para 1. What's implied by the code is -2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the value of add_res and mul_res have to be known at the time add_res is loaded into a register.

Note that the process is sensitive to clk but doesn't use an edge nor qualify with a value of clk.

I modified your architecture to qualify add_res update to the rising edge of clk. There's a built in assumption you have non-metavalue values on mult_res at that time. That can be dealt with in part by defining a default initial value.

Also the new value of A is not available until signals are update, which doesn't occur while there are any processes pending to be resumed in the current simulation cycle. This means you need to assign to add_res (which holds the accumulated value anyway) and assign to A outside the process:

```
ARCHITECTURE mac_rtl OF mac IS
      SIGNAL mul_res: SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0'); -- added init val
      SIGNAL add_res: SIGNED (31 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
BEGIN

      mul_res <= B * C;

      PROCESS (clk)
      BEGIN
          if rising_edge(clk) then  -- ADDED
              -- A <= mul_res + add_res;  CHANGED
              add_res <= mul_res + add_res;
              -- add_res <= A;            CHANGED
          end if;                   -- ADDED
      END PROCESS;

      A <= add_res; 

END mac_rtl;
```

And this gives:

[image: mac_testbench_fixed.png]

You could note there is no need to try to collapse A and add_res. For simulation purposes delta cycles caused by signal assignments that take effect after 0 simulation time has passed do not take simulation time.

Scheduled signal updates and delta cycles are used to emulate concurrency in signals that are inherently assigned sequentially. (And yes in the modified architecture the assignment to A will occur one delta cycle later than add_res).

(And yes I put a StopClock transaction at the tail end of the stimuli in process Stimulus in the testbench).

Comment: Thank you very much. It's so silly that I forgot to use the rising edge of the clock, because I thought it wasn't needed for that implementation. Now everything works as it should.